# Binding a CRF++ tool to python

Tags: python, nlp, crf++

I have built a program using CRF++ tool for Natural Language Processing and now I want to give the output of that code to python. how can I do that? Please help...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help answer the question if you could provide more details. Can you post the CRF++ code that you have written?

Comment: actually I created a data set and trained to create a module. and I want to send the output of that to python..... this is my output.
සමන්ට NN 1

ලැබුන VB 0

කළු ADJ 1

පූසන් NN 1

ගණන QW 1

කීයද QW 1

I need to run CRF++ tool in python environment..

Comment: You could always pipe CRF++'s output to a text file and then pick that up in your Python script.